# How to show content by scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have written some html code for my webpage in which multiple images are shown. the problem is, all the images are loaded at the starting itself. I want to change that to show extra images by scrolling down. How to do that with jQuery?

The code is:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block content %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
      </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I just want to add javascript so that when the page is scrolled down, the images will be loaded. I tried the code from codepen website, but it is working. How to solve this?

Comment: Hope this is helpful. http://webresourcesdepot.com/lazy-loading-of-images-resources-you-need/

Comment: Use [LazyLoad](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload)

Answer (score 2):

This would help :)

Run the code snippet and check.

As you keep scrolling the page, the remaining images on the screen would get displayed if the window scroll position is greater than the last image scroll position.

```js
function showImages(){
    
  var imgStartIndex = 0;
  var nextSetOfImages = 10;
  var incrementImageLimit = 10;
  var collectionOfImages = $(".thumbnail img");
  var noOfImages = collectionOfImages.length;

  return function(){
  
    for (var i = imgStartIndex; i < nextSetOfImages; i++){
      $(collectionOfImages[i]).fadeIn().addClass("shown");
    } 

    imgStartIndex = imgStartIndex + incrementImageLimit;
    nextSetOfImages = imgStartIndex + nextSetOfImages;
    nextSetOfImages = (nextSetOfImages >= noOfImages) ? noOfImages : nextSetOfImages;

  };
    
}

var disImg = showImages();

$(document).ready(function(){
  disImg();
  
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    
    var scollPostion = $(window).scrollTop();
    var imgShownLast = $(".thumbnail img.shown").last();
    var imgShowFist = $(".thumbnail img.shown").first();
    var imgLastScrollPos = $(imgShownLast).offset().top;
    var imgFirstScrollPos = $(imgShowFist).offset().top;
    scollPostion = scollPostion + imgFirstScrollPos + 200; 
    if(scollPostion > imgLastScrollPos){ 
      disImg();
    }
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.thumbnail img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
      <h2>Pictures of Coffee</h2>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/5JVPSVP7EI.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/C5Y10KIIHA.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/YSSFRY5B25.jpg" alt=""></div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: .thumbnail img class is not present in my code, where should i put this class? Or do i have to change it to the class name i have specified?

Comment: . thumbnail is added to the div element which wraps the IMG tag

Comment: Could you add your code to a fiddle, so we can narrow down the issue.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h2qp0SPW8gJWfN4SqAyV5nMr1lIK7c7g  this is the entire project link. it is written using django framework. So i am attaching all the code. Please check this

Answer (score 0):

event for scroll is:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

 //write your logics to load your images as per requirements

})
```

Comment: can you write the script for the above code. I am not getting. please

Answer (score 0):

First of all bootstrap divide a row in 12 columns so for example:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 thumbnail"><img src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/04LDEYRW59.jpg" alt=""></div>
             <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/90V03Q5Y60.jpg" alt=""></div>
             <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4 thumbnail"><img  src="https://d2lm6fxwu08ot6.cloudfront.net/img-thumbs/960w/O83SF2RB6D.jpg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

use another row with columns like above (in the container). To make the scroll effects you need three components: Animate ccs https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
viewportchecker https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker jquery http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js
Follow this example add this in the tag head of the html template. Where you find href or src you must overwrite with the path where you store the three files above OR you can directly use external file, for example http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animate.css" />
<script src="viewportchecker.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
    .hidden{opacity:0;}
    .visible{opacity:1;}
</style>
```

in the body tag add this, replace the container with your code BUT remember that the script add the effect to ".post" class so maybe you will want change the name of your code class or you can also change the class in the script:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
            <div class="post"> <!-- Post content goes here --> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From which website do i have to download css and js files

Comment: sorry, this is so confusing

Comment: animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/ viewport: https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker

Comment: what is test.js here? You didnt use it anywhere

Comment: it's just an example you can put it in the body inside <script> tag or you can make an external file and call it in the head tag.

P.S. if you like my answer mark it as useful

Comment: I am sorry, it is not so clear for me. And another question is, do i have to install viewport-checker file?